# Errors in scanning variables at runtime

Tags: compiler-errors, expression, java.util.scanner, unresolved-external

I'm beginner to Java programming. I want to solve an expression of the form
(a+2<sup>0</sup>b)+(a+2<sup>0</sup>b+2<sup>1</sup>b)+........+(a+2<sup>0</sup>b+...+2<sup>(n-1)</sup>b) where you are given "q" queries in the form of a, b  and n for each query, print the expression value corresponding to the given a, b and n values. That means
Sample Input:
2
0 2 10
5 3 5
Sample Output:
4072
196
My code was:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Expression {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
    }
    int expr=a+b;                 //ERROR:a cannot be resolved to a variable
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)       //ERROR:n cannot be resolved to a variable
        expr+=a+Math.pow(2, i)*b; //ERROR:a and b cannot be resolved to variables
    System.out.print(expr);
    in.close();
}

}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are declared just in the for loop, so they won't be visible outside of it. Declare them outside of the for loop. Same goes for `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is declaring `a`, `b` and `n` in the `for` loop, that means that when the loop ends the variables too will be lost and the garbage collector will take care of them.

The solution to this is really easy

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q=in.nextInt();
    int a, b, n;               // Declare outside if you need them outside ;)
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();
        n = in.nextInt();
    }
    int expr=a+b;              //ERROR:a cannot be resolved to a variable
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++) {  //ERROR:n cannot be resolved to a variable
        expr+=a+(2*i)*b;       //ERROR:a and b cannot be resolved to variables
        System.out.print(expr);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I've got a new error at the same lines saying that "the local variable a and b and n may not have been initialized". What to do?

Comment: Assign a value to those 3 variables when you initialise them, so that if the Scanner fails to read a value the variable can still be used during runtime